# Failing to call a call paintcomponent method :(

Tags: java, actionlistener, paintcomponent

What I am trying to achieve is that the program would draw a line in the middle of the frame as soon as the user has clicked draw. But sadly nothing is happening other than "frame 3" is disappearing. Any ideas about how I could fix the problem?

Here is the method:

Windowj is my frame. Frame3 is the previous frame please don't worry about it.

```
public static void graf() {
    frame3.setVisible(false);
    windowj.setSize(400, 500);
    windowj.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    windowj.setResizable(false);
    windowj.setLayout(null);
    windowj.setVisible(true);
    windowj.setTitle("Graphs");
    windowj.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    xinwindow.setBounds(30,40, 90, 40);
    yinwindow.setBounds(100,100,90,40);
    thefunction.setBounds(200,300,90,40);
    draw.setBounds(300,200,90,40 );

    windowj.add(xinwindow);
    windowj.add(yinwindow);
    windowj.add(thefunction);
    windowj.add(draw);
    c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,200));

    draw.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            windowj.add(c);
            c.revalidate();
            c.repaint();



        }
```

And here is the paintcomponent method:

```
private static Component c = new JComponent() {
     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);


        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawLine(50, 0, 70 , 100);


    }
};
```

Any help would be appreciated, and please try to keep it simple, I am a beginner. :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: Show plz jframe code

Comment: I am telling you that information is missing from your question. It is hard to answer incomplete questions. If you have want us to help, you have to enable us to do so.

Comment: I see it is your second question about this subject. For better help post proper question, including mcve as already asked.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you use `windowj` as your `JFrame` and that what will happen when you click draw button your use `windowj.setVisible(false)` and that will make your window disappear
so remove it
2nd thing is you need to put your Component in windowj as `windowj.add(c);` in your draw ActionListener at actionPerformed before `c.revalidate();`
and here a little code that I wrote to understand what I mean:

```
public class DrawLine {

    private JFrame windowj = new JFrame();
    private JButton draw = new JButton();

    private static int width = 640, height = 480;

    private static JComponent c    = new JComponent() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawLine((width/2) - 1, 0, (width/2) +1 , height);
        }
    };

    public DrawLine() {

        windowj.setDefaultCloseOperation(windowj.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        windowj.setSize(width, height);
        windowj.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        windowj.setResizable(false);
        windowj.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        windowj.setVisible(true);

        draw = new JButton("Draw");
        draw.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //i don't know why you set windowj(windowj) false but that will close your window
                //windowj.setVisible(false);
                //add component to windowj(windowj)
                windowj.add(c);
                c.revalidate();
                c.repaint();
            }
        });

        c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height-100));
        windowj.add(draw);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DrawLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello!
Thanks for your answer! I tried but it didn't work (nothing happens when I click draw). I have edited the question with the new code. Could you please take a look and see why it is not displaying anything? thanks :)

Comment: sorry for late answer but from what you Edit up in your code you use bonds to mange your layout so instead of using c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height-100)); you will need to use c.setBonds(x, y, width, height); and see where you put it in your frame i will attach a code that i modified it for you hope this will help you to understand it

Answer (score -1):

Here is the modified code:

```
private JFrame frame3, windowj;
private JPanel xinwindow, yinwindow,thefunction; 
private JButton draw;

private static Component c = new JComponent() {
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawLine(50, 0, 70 , 100);
    }
};

public DrawLine() {
    xinwindow = new JPanel();
    yinwindow = new JPanel();
    thefunction = new JPanel();
    draw = new JButton("Draw");
    //i ignored frame3 as you said so just ignore my implementation here
    frame3 = new JFrame();
    frame3.setVisible(false);

    windowj = new JFrame();
    windowj.setSize(400, 500);
    windowj.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    windowj.setResizable(false);
    windowj.setLayout(null);
    windowj.setVisible(true);
    windowj.setTitle("Graphs");
    windowj.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    /*i used setBackground(Color.anycolor); to make it easier for me to know where
    your window is in your frame*/
    xinwindow.setBackground(Color.RED);
    xinwindow.setBounds(30,40, 90, 40);
    yinwindow.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    yinwindow.setBounds(100,100,90,40);
    thefunction.setBounds(200,300,90,40);
    thefunction.setBackground(Color.green);
    draw.setBounds(300,200,90,40 );

    windowj.add(xinwindow);
    windowj.add(yinwindow);
    windowj.add(thefunction);
    windowj.add(draw);
    //here use setBonds instead of setPreferredSize
    c.setBounds(100, 200, 200, 200);

    draw.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            windowj.add(c);
            c.revalidate();
            c.repaint();
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DrawLine();
}
```

hope that solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help. It worked :)